# forbid ADB install apk through a password

Tags: adb

pls is there a way to forbid the adb install to install apk into tablets unless there's a password?

Android 5.0 - rooted devices?

thank you

Comment: Do you mean using the command line with adb or through the Play Store / APK Files on device ?

Comment: I want users not to be able to apply "adb install" command from pc unless there s a password or something. I've removed the play store,& put the applications needed & removed the settings too before unroot.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to turn off USB debugging.

If you want to disable `adb install` from computer while enabling USB debugging, you can try [XInstaller](http://repo.xposed.info/module/com.pyler.xinstaller) (Requires Xposed Framework). In its settings you can disable "Auto Install" to prevent ALL kinds of silent installation.

Answer (score -1):

well simply, 
activate the developper options & then disable usb debugging then decativate the developper otions & delete the settings!
Hope this will help others.